# Snakemake - controlling which wildcards are used in input/output

Tags: python, wildcard, bioinformatics, snakemake

I have a rule that takes one VCF spanning multiple regions of interest that can vary, and splits it by chromosome (using a list) to generate per-chromosome VCFs for each region:

```
chrom = [chr1, chr2, chr3, ...]

rule split_vcf:
    input:
        vcf = "called/{region}.vcf.gz",                      #i.e.region1.vcf.gz
        index = "called/{region}.vcf.gz.tbi",
    output:
        vcf = "called/splitvcf/{chrom}_{region}.vcf.gz",     #i.e. .../chr1_region1.vcf.gz
        index = "called/splitvcf/{chrom}_{region}.vcf.gz.tbi",
    shell:
        "bcftools view -r {wildcards.chrom} {output.vcf}" # where chrom = ["chr1","chr22",...]

# Should be able to go from:
inputs: 
region1.vcf.gz, 
region2.vcf.gz, 


outputs: 
chr1_region1.vcf.gz, 
chr2_region2.vcf.gz, 
chr1_region2.vcf.gz, 
chr2_region1.vcf.gz
```

Followed by a rule that will collapse the per-chromosome VCFs over many regions, into one VCF for each chromosome which should look like:

```
rule combine_vcfs:
    input:
        vcfs = expand("called/split/{{chrom}}_{region}.vcf.gz"),        # i.e. chr1_region1.vcf.gz
        index = expand("called/split/{{chrom}}_{region}.vcf.gz.tbi"),
    output:
        vcf = "called/splitvcf/{chrom}.vcf.gz",        # i.e. chr1.vcf.gz, chr2.vcf.gz, ...
        index = "called/splitvcf/{chrom}.vcf.gz.tbi",
    shell:
        "bcftools concat {input.vcfs} ..."

# Should be able to go from:
inputs: 
chr1_region1.vcf.gz, 
chr2_region2.vcf.gz, 
chr1_region2.vcf.gz, 
chr2_region1.vcf.gz

outputs: 
chr1.vcf.gz,
chr2.vcf.gz
```

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get `rule combine_vcfs` to correctly expand and provide a list to the shell command such that the wildcard for `{{chrom}}` stays constant, and avoid using other wildcards in the output, where you would combine all files with the wildcard for `chrom` being `{chr1}`, and same for other subsequent values for `chrom`.

My attempt:
I created a function to glob over the output of `rule split_vcf` to create a list of files using `{wildcards.chrom}` to then pass into the input block of the second rule but this seems to mess up my DAG such that `rule combine_chroms` gets evaluated first.

Something like:

```
def get_vcfs(wildcards):
    indir = pathlib.Path("called/split/")
    ff = [str(x) for x in indir.glob(f"{wildcards.chrom}_*.vcf.gz")]
    return sorted(ff)
```

What are some better ways of doing this?
Things I have pondered:

- Should I make `rule split_vcf` a checkpoint, then aggregate outputs of it afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know which values the wildcard `{region}` takes, this should do:

```
REGION=['region1', 'region2', etc]

rule combine_vcfs:
    input:
        vcfs = expand("called/split/{{chrom}}_{region}.vcf.gz", region=REGION),
    ...
```